# Gson getAsString() fails if json array is empty

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm using the Json library Gson in Java to parse json strings into CSV files. Some of my json fields are null so I will have to check for that and add an empty string instead. Some of the fields in my json strings are arrays and some of them are empty. However, when these arrays are empty, the getAsString method in Gson fails with illeagStateException. Here is a runnable example:

```
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;

JsonObject message = new JsonParser().parse("{\"id\":null,\"text\":\"test\",\"types\":[]}").getAsJsonObject();
JsonElement element = message.get("types"); //now this is "[]"
String jsonElementAsString= element.isJsonNull() ? "" : element.getAsString(); //Here exception is thrown.
```

I'm already checking if json is null. What is a good workaround here? I would like to avoid adding to much clutter in order to improve execution time. I could of course wrap it all in a try catch but that is expensive.

Comment: May be try gson.fromJson("string", Map.class)

Comment: and i'm not sure why you are trying to get `JsonArray` as string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since we know `types` is an Array, the best way i would do is, first check `types` is existed in `JsonObject`

```
if(message.has("types"))  //which avoids null pointer exception
```

Then get the `types` as `JsonArray`

```
JsonArray typesArray = message.getAsJsonArray("types");
```

And then use `forEach` so you don't need to care if array is empty also

```
typesArray.forEach(element->System.out.println(element));
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work. Still, as I'm going to parse a few hundred thousand rows of JSON, even a single extra check adds up.

Comment: to avoid exceptions you need the checks @Baxtex